# How to use a picker on CoreData relationships in SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui, picker

G'day everyone,

I'm trying to work out how CoreData relationships can work with UI elements like pickers.

At the moment I have a 3 view app (based on the Xcode boilerplate code) which displays a list of parent entities, which have children which have children. I want a picker to select which grandchild a child entity should refer to.

At the moment I have two funny side effects:

1. When I run the app as a preview (so there is pre-populated data... this sample code will break without the data in place),

- the selected grandchild in the picker is the grandchild of the first
  child, irrespective of which child you're dropped into in the first
  view.
- When I drop back and pick another child, now the picked grabs the correct initial selection from the child entity

2. When I select a child and "save" that, the value in the child summary does not change, until I click another child at which point the value changes before the transition to the modal view.

I am clearly missing something in my understanding of the sequence of events when presenting modals in SwiftUI... can any what shed any light on what I've done wrong?

Here's a video to make this more clear:
https://github.com/andrewjdavison/Test31/blob/main/Test31%20-%20first%20click%20issue.mov?raw=true

Git repository of the sample is https://github.com/andrewjdavison/Test31.git, but in summary:

Data Model:
[image: Data Model]

View Source:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData


struct LicenceView : View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Binding var licence: Licence
    @Binding var showModal: Bool
    
    @State var selectedElement: Element
    @FetchRequest private var elements: FetchedResults<Element>
    
    init(currentLicence: Binding<Licence>, showModal: Binding<Bool>, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self._licence = currentLicence
        self._showModal = showModal
        
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Element> = Element.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = []
        self._elements = FetchRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
        
        _selectedElement = State(initialValue: currentLicence.wrappedValue.licenced!)
    }
        
    func save() {
        licence.licenced = selectedElement
        try! viewContext.save()
        showModal = false
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {showModal = false}) {
                Text("Close")
            }
            Picker(selection: $selectedElement, label: Text("Element")) {
                ForEach(elements, id: \.self) { element in
                    Text("\(element.desc!)")
                }
            }
            Text("Selected: \(selectedElement.desc!)")
            Button(action: {save()}) {
                Text("Save")
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct RegisterView : View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @State var showModal: Bool = false
    var currentRegister: Register
    
    @State var currentLicence: Licence
    
    init(currentRegister: Register) {
        currentLicence = Array(currentRegister.licencedUsers! as! Set<Licence>)[0]
        self.currentRegister = currentRegister
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach (Array(currentRegister.licencedUsers! as! Set<Licence>), id: \.self) { licence in
                    Button(action: {currentLicence = licence; showModal = true}) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(licence.leasee!) : ")
                            Text("\(licence.licenced!.desc!)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
            LicenceView(currentLicence: $currentLicence, showModal: $showModal, context: viewContext )
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Register.id, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var registers: FetchedResults<Register>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(registers) { register in
                    NavigationLink(destination: RegisterView(currentRegister: register)) {
                        Text("Register id \(register.id!)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfaNb.png
```

Comment: Likely because you aren't observing the changes in the `ObservableObjects`/ CoreData objects. Don't use `@Binding` or `@State` with `ObservableObjects`/ CoreData objects use `@ObservedObject` instead. That will also let you get rid of the made up `@FetchRequest` in the `LicenceView` and the `selectedElement` because you can use use `$licence.licenced` instead. Just as a rule, SwiftUI does not work well using Custom `init`s if you find yourself doing all of this work in a custom `init` you need to rethink your approach. SwiftUI reloads `View` whenever it wants and your variables will reset.

Comment: Also, in `RegisterView` you are probably better off using `sheet(item:)` and `@State var currentLicence: Licence?`. Knowing that you won't see any changes with this variable, because it isn't observing, its sole purpose is to trigger the `sheet`. If you want to see the changes you have to use `@ObservedObject` in a subview

Comment: Thanks - some good time in there. Interestingly, when I do switch to an ObservableObject and use $licence.licenced in the picker selected: field, it no longer updates the relationship, so when I save it and pop the view, it reverts to its original value... In fact the text below the picker never updated either, which I would have thought it would do...

Comment: Your picker is missing the tag. Selection doesn’t know there is a change

Comment: Thanks again. I had added the tag, but it didn't appear to make a difference. I have added a branch called "ObservedObjectBranch" to the repo above which has incorporated your recommendations... 

At the moment the only problem outstanding is that the picker is not reflecting its changes into the Licence object.

If you wouldn't mind having a look I'd really appreciate it. In the meantime - I'm off to watch the WWDC21 video!

Comment: Likely a type thing try changing your tag to `.tag(element as Element?)` and of course `licence.licenced` should be an `Element`

Comment: You should also look into [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app) `@ObservedObject` should not be initialized in the same `View` that it lives in. It should come from the previous `View`. You will have a leak and some instability if you do it on `init`

Comment: Thanks again - trying to get rid of all my inits based on your comments. The only reason I've been using them was to get around the problems I was experiencing using @State.

That's nailed the problem. Interestingly using "as Element" didn't work, but "as Element?" did. Why is that?

Comment: Because the the `licenced` is an optional in your model. The types have to match.

Comment: Oh D'oh! of course. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237027/discussion-between-andy-davison-and-lorem-ipsum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Huge vote of thanks to Lorem for getting me to the answer. Thanks too for Roma, but it does turn out that his solution, whilst it worked to resolve one of my key problems, does introduce inefficiencies - and didn't resolve the second one.

If others are hitting the same issue I'll leave the Github repo up, but the crux of it all was that @State shouldn't be used when you're sharing CoreData objects around. @ObservedObject is the way to go here.

So the resolution to the problems I encountered were:

1. Use @ObservedObject instead of @State for passing around the CoreData objects
2. Make sure that the picker has a tag defined. The documentation I head read implied that this gets generated automatically if you use ".self" as the id for the objects in ForEach, but it seems this is not always reliable. so adding ".tag(element as Element?)" to my picker helped here.
   Note: It needed to be an optional type because CoreData makes all the attribute types optional.

Those two alone fixed the problems.

The revised "LicenceView" struct is here, but the whole solution is in the repo.

Cheers!

```
struct LicenceView : View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @ObservedObject var licence: Licence
    @Binding var showModal: Bool
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Element.desc, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var elements: FetchedResults<Element>
    
    func save() {
        try! viewContext.save()
        showModal = false
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {showModal = false}) {
                Text("Close")
            }
            Picker(selection: $licence.licenced, label: Text("Element")) {
                ForEach(elements, id: \.self) { element in
                    Text("\(element.desc!)")
                        .tag(element as Element?)
                }
            }
            Text("Selected: \(licence.licenced!.desc!)")
            Button(action: {save()}) {
                Text("Save")
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really understand this

```
• selected grandchild in the picker is the grandchild of the first child, irrespective of which child you're dropped into in the first view.
• When I drop back and pick another child, now the picked grabs the correct initial selection from the child entity
```

Could you attach a video that represents a problem?

But I can give you a solution to the preview problem and the second one.

## Preview

If you use preview with Core Data, you need to use a `viewContext`created with MockData and pass it to your View. Here I provide a generic code, that can be modified for each of your views:

In your `Persistance` struct (CoreData Manager) declare a variable preview with your preview Items:

```
static var preview: PersistenceController = {
    let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
    let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
    // Here you create your Mock Data
    let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
    newItem.yourProperty = yourValue
    
    do {
        try viewContext.save()
    } catch {
       // error handling
    }
    return result
}()
```

Make sure it has `inMemory: Bool` in its init, as it is responsible for separating real viewContext and previewContext:

```
init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
    container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestCD")
    if inMemory {
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
    }
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
}
```

Create Mock Item from your viewContext and pass it to preview:

```
     struct YourView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            let context = PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext
            let request: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
            let fetchedItems = try! context.fetch(request)
            YourView(item: fetchedItems)
        }
    }
```

If you use `@FetchRequest` and `@FetchedResults` it makes it easier, as they will do creating and fetching objects for you. Just implement a preview like this:

```
     struct YourView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            YourView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
```

Here is Persistence struct created by Xcode at the moment of the project initialization:

```
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        let item = Item(context: viewContext)
        item.property = yourProperty
        
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
          
        }
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestCD")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
               
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

## Second problem

Core Data objects are built with classes, so their type is a reference. When you change a property is a class it doesn't notifiy the view struct to redraw with a new value. (exception is classes, that are created to notify about changes.)

You need to explicitly tell your `RegisterView` struct to redraw itself after you dismiss your `LicenceView`. You can do it by creating one more variable in your `RegisterView` - `@State var id = UUID()`. Then attach an `.id(id)` modifier at the end of your `VStack`

```
VStack {
    //your code
}.id(id)
```

Finally, create a function `viewDismissed` which will change the `id` property in your struct:

```
func viewDismissed() {
    id = UUID()
}
```

Now, attach this function to your sheet with an optional parameter `onDismiss`

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showModal, onDismiss: viewDismissed) {
      LicenceView(currentLicence: $currentLicence, showModal: $showModal, context: viewContext )
        }
```

Comment: Thanks - the second one did the trick for the Element updates nicely. 

I'll add a video for the other problem shortly.

Comment: Video link is https://github.com/andrewjdavison/Test31/blob/main/Test31%20-%20first%20click%20issue.mov?raw=true

Comment: Using the id trick is inefficient. CoreData objects are observable objects Apple has provided wrappers for observing changes. You should watch Demystify SwiftUI from WWDC21, instead of having a targeted refresh you are just reloading it all

Comment: Thanks Lorem... agreed. Working to get everything cut over to Observable objects for CoreData...